# How to calculate dot product with broadcasting?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting, dot-product

```
a=np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
b=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
```

I wanna calculate the dot product

```
a[0]@b[0]
array([ 5, 14, 23])

a[1]@b[1]
array([122, 158, 194])
```

With broadcasting, I tried

```
c=a@b[...,None]
c
array([[[  5],
        [ 14],
        [ 23]],

       [[122],
        [158],
        [194]]])
```

But the shape is not what I want

```
c.shape
(2, 3, 1)
```

1. How can I get the shape `(2, 3)` instead of `(2, 3, 1)`in the calculation, other than the way changing the axes?
2. For broadcasting, why `[:,None]` doesn't work? what does `...` mean here?

Comment: You aren't really broadcasting.  You expand the dimensions of `b` before it is used in the product.  `a@b.T` does use broadcasting, expanding the `b.T` to (1,3,2) to (3,3,2), which `dots` to produce (2,3,2).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `b[...,None]` is the same as `b[:,:,None]`, a (2,3,1) array.  `...` means 'as many `:` as needed'.

So the dot product sum is with the last `3` of `a` and the middle `3` of `b` (2nd to the last).

You can use `squeeze` to get rid of the size 1 dimension.

But with (2,3,3) and (2,3), which `dot` product do you want? In `einsum` notation I can see doing

```
'ijk,ij->ik'
'ijk,ik->ij'
'ijk,mj->imk'
etc
```

`dot` product with 2 2d arrays is well defined.  But when one is 3d there's some ambiguity.

```
In [2]: a=np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
   ...: b=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
   ...: 

In [3]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',a,b)
Out[3]: 
array([[  5,  14,  23],
       [122, 158, 194]])

In [4]: np.dot(a,b)
ValueError: shapes (2,3,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 2) != 2 (dim 0)

In [6]: np.dot(a,b[:,:,None]).shape  # 'ijk,kml->ijml'
Out[6]: (2, 3, 2, 1)

In [7]: np.matmul(a,b[:,:,None]).shape   # @ 
Out[7]: (2, 3, 1)
In [8]: np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm',a,b[...,None])
Out[8]: 
array([[[  5],
        [ 14],
        [ 23]],

       [[122],
        [158],
        [194]]])

In [12]: np.squeeze(_)   # removing that added dimension
Out[12]: 
array([[  5,  14,  23],
       [122, 158, 194]])
```

The relevant notes from `matmul` docs are:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of
>     matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.
>
> ValueError - If the last dimension of `a` is not the same size as
>       the second-to-last dimension of `b`.

---

An example of broadcasting in `matmul` is:

```
In [15]: a@b.T
Out[15]: 
array([[[  5,  14],
        [ 14,  50],
        [ 23,  86]],

       [[ 32, 122],
        [ 41, 158],
        [ 50, 194]]])

In [16]: _.shape
Out[16]: (2, 3, 2)

In [17]: a@b.T[None,:,:]
Out[17]: 
array([[[  5,  14],
        [ 14,  50],
        [ 23,  86]],

       [[ 32, 122],
        [ 41, 158],
        [ 50, 194]]])
```

### update

I just learned that `optimize=True` is now the default for `einsum`, and that this isn't always fastest.

```
In [108]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',a,b, optimize=False)
5.66 µs ± 63.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [109]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',a,b, optimize=True)
73 µs ± 69.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[Einsum optimize fails for basic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727096/einsum-optimize-fails-for-basic-operation)

Comment: Thx, I edit my question again, and I wanna dot product `a[0]@b[0]` and `a[1]@b[1]`. Can I still use `@` operator to achieve the shape `(2,3)` ?

Comment: @kinderchan, according to the `matmul` rules, you need to expand `b` so it is 3d.  The last dim of `a` has to match the 2nd to last of `b`.  To get (2,3) you have squeeze out the dimension that you added - afterwards.

Comment: thx for everything, I think `np.einsum` may make a better way.