# Einsum optimize fails for basic operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, numpy-einsum

With the recent update to Numpy (1.14), I found that it breaks my entire codebase. This is based on changing the default numpy einsum optimize argument from False to True.

As a result, the following basic operation now fails:

```
a = np.random.random([50, 2, 2])
b = np.random.random([50, 2])

np.einsum('bdc, ac -> ab', a, b, optimize=True)
```

with the following error trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-b0f9ce3c71a3> in <module>()
----> 1 np.einsum('bdc, ac -> ab', a, b, optimize=True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\einsumfunc.py in 
einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
   1118 
   1119             # Contract!
-> 1120             new_view = tensordot(*tmp_operands, axes=
(tuple(left_pos), tuple(right_pos)))
   1121 
   1122             # Build a new view if needed

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in 
tensordot(a, b, axes)
   1301     oldb = [bs[axis] for axis in notin]
   1302 
-> 1303     at = a.transpose(newaxes_a).reshape(newshape_a)
   1304     bt = b.transpose(newaxes_b).reshape(newshape_b)
   1305     res = dot(at, bt)

 ValueError: axes don't match array
```

The operation I'm requesting from einsum seems very simple... so why does it fail? If I set "optimize=False", it works just fine.

I tried exploring with einsum_path but the resulting path info was the same with and without optimization.

Comment: Can it be because the code now tries to use BLAS "whenever possible" - see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.14.0-notes.rst ? Maybe it would be better to open an issue on https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: I think `path` is useful when there are 3 or more arguments, and there's a question of which `dot` contraction should be done first (to reduce the problem space fastest).  This is a different sort of contraction problem.

Comment: I need to pay more attention to this `optimize` parameter when recommending `einsum`, especially when using `timeit` tests.  It's harder to know whether it's using the original `c_einsum` or one of these supposed optimizations.

Comment: I found the bug issue, #10343.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [40]: a=np.ones((50,2,2),int); b=np.ones((50,2),int)
In [41]: np.einsum('bdc,ac->ab', a, b)
... 
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

I don't see what optimization has to do with this error.

For the first argument `b,d,c` are 50,2,2.  For the second `a,c` are 50,2. The result should be 50,50.  But what happened to `d`?

```
In [43]: np.einsum('bdc,ac->abd', a, b).shape
Out[43]: (50, 50, 2)
```

---

Oops:

```
In [49]: np.einsum('bdc,ac->ab', a, b, optimize=False).shape
Out[49]: (50, 50)
```

So it's summing on `d`.

---

Note the error - with optimization, it uses `tensordot` (transpose plus `dot`), rather than the original `einsum` `nditer` approach.

`c_einsum` is the one that can handle that missing `d`:

```
# If no optimization, run pure einsum
if optimize_arg is False:
    return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
```

---

Tried some timings:

Two step calculation with the default optimize:

```
In [64]: timeit np.einsum('abd->ab', np.einsum('bdc,ac->abd', a, b))
288 µs ± 518 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The desired `c_einsum` is faster

```
In [65]: timeit np.einsum('bdc,ac->ab', a, b, optimize=False)
170 µs ± 83.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In fact `c_einsum` is faster even when the `tensordot` version works

```
In [67]: timeit np.einsum('bdc,ac->abd', a, b,optimize=False)
73.1 µs ± 46.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [68]: timeit np.einsum('bdc,ac->abd', a, b,optimize=True)
207 µs ± 6.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This example might be too small to show of the advantages of `tensordot/blas`.

Looks like this has been raised on github - both the failures, and the slower 'optimize' speed: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10343 "einsum broadcast regression (with optimize=True)"

Comment: Because in v1.13 the optimize flag defaulted to False. If you run this code, with the flag set manually, it does work: np.einsum('bdc,ac->ab', a, b, optimize=False) gives array([[4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       ...,
       [4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4]])

Comment: Similarly, in v1.13, if you manually set optimize=True, you get the error. Thus, I feel the bug lies with the optimization function? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I don't have 1.13 installed any more, so can't test that behavior.  I should probably delete this answer.  I studied `einsum` in depth back several versions, but haven't paid much attention to the recent optimization.

Comment: Ok, sure. Thanks for your help. I believe this issue still stands then.

Comment: I just realized that with optimization it doesn't use the `nditer` approach that I studied - it uses `tensordot`.

Comment: _"Similarly, in v1.13, if you manually set optimize=True, you get the error."_ - **not true!** I will post an answer just to prove this and I will delete it in 10 min.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying! It seems the devs are aware of this bug though: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10343 and a possible fix: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10352.   Therefore, for now, I'll just manually disable optimization and wait until v1.15 when it optimize will either work / be disabled by default again.